# SQL SELECT row with highest value where problem_id is the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dao

I'm working on a project where I have to list the solutions with the highest votes per problem.

Every problem has two solutions and the users can vote on one solution per problem. This is my database at the moment.

```
+----------+------------+---------+
|    id    | id_problem |  vote   |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    1     |     1      |    25   |
|    2     |     1      |    10   |
|    3     |     2      |    18   |
|    4     |     2      |    2    |
|    5     |     3      |    6    |
|    6     |     3      |    7    |
|    7     |     4      |    11   |
|    8     |     4      |    4    |
|    9     |     5      |    5    |
|    10    |     5      |    2    |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

I would like to get this result:
(The row with the highest vote per `id_problem`)

```
+----------+------------+---------+
|    id    | id_problem |  vote   |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    1     |     1      |    25   |
|    3     |     2      |    18   |
|    6     |     3      |    7    |
|    7     |     4      |    11   |
|    9     |     5      |    5    |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    id_problem, 
    max(vote) 
from 
    tablename
group by 
    id_problem 
order by 
    id_problem ASC
```

The max(vote) determines greater vote, but it aggregate the result, then you need to group by id_problem and then order it asc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` clause with `max` aggregation function to get the expected result, e.g.:

```
select id, id_problem, max(vote) as vote
from result
group by id_problem
order by id_problem
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/909d14/1/0)**.

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants id as well since it's the PK.